# How to make a class follow another in python

Tags: python, class, sprite

How do I make a class follow another, instead of moving in a single direction?

for example:

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    char_walk1 = pygame.image.load("").convert_alpha()
    char_walk2 = pygame.image.load("").convert_alpha()
    self.char_walk = [char_walk1, char_walk2]
    self.char_index = 0
    self.image = self.char_walk[self.char_index]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(100, 100))

def update(self):
    key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_input[pygame.K_d]:
        self.rect.x += 3
    if key_input[pygame.K_a]:
        self.rect.x -= 3
```

Here the Character is moving left or right per key press and,

```
class Mobs(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    mob_walk1 = pygame.image.load("").convert_alpha()
    mob_walk2 = pygame.image.load("").convert_alpha()
    self.frames = [mob_walk1, mob_walk2]
    pos = 452

    self.mob_index = 0
    self.image = self.frames[self.mob_index]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(randint(200, 200), pos))

def update(self):
self.rect.x -= 3
```

Here the mob is moving right, How do I make it follow the character around on screen?

Character is sprite.Groupsingle and Mobs is sprite.Group

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a reference to the character as an attribute in the Mobs class. then in the update method you'll have to decide the direction of the movement based on the relative position of the character.

```
def update(self):

    if self.character.rect.x < self.rect.x:
        self.rect.x -= 3
    else:
        self.sect.x += 3
  
It's been a while since i fooled around with pygame so I'm not sure about the best way to implement it but I hope it at least serves as guidance.
```